# Same size to all TabItem in TabControl

Tags: wpf-controls

It looks like simple issue but I failed to figure out how to do it.

I have a TabControl inside window with two TabItem. One of the TabItem has a fixed size content while the other TabItem's content is changing by the user mode.

I don't want to set the size of the window fixed to the biggest content.

I want the window to extend and shrink by the mode user chooses, but when user chooses a mode, I want both tabs to be the same size.

The TabControl HorizontalElignment was set to Streach.This didn't help because the window width itself changes by the content. Is there any way to set the smaller TabItem size and bind to the Larger one? Or maybe there is other solution?

Comment: What do you mean "by the mode user chose"?  Also, if you have some current code, post it!